# Referencing object from user input string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, object

I'm having a problem referencing the fields of my object from a string. Apparently I'm not allowed to do that and I'm guessing it's because the string references an entirely different memory location since it is it's own object. But I have no idea how I can do this better. Here's the code

```
class Truck:

    width = 48

    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 480
        self.height = 108

standardTruck = Truck()

class Bale:

    def __init__(self, length, height, width):
        self.length = length
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

sewer1 = Bale(240, 18, 24)
c9001 = Bale(480, 8, 32)
ips1 = Bale(120, 30, 30)
sewer2 = Bale(240, 20, 28)
c9002 = Bale(480, 10, 30)
ips2 = Bale (120, 12, 60)
sewer3 = Bale(240, 32, 40)
c9003 = Bale(480, 10, 40)
ips2 = Bale(120, 32, 48)


bale1 = input("What bale do you want?")
bale1Q = input("How many do you want?")


print("You chose " + bale1Q + " bales of " + bale1 + ". This bale has a width of " + bale1.width + " a height of " + bale1.height + " and a length of " + bale1.length + ".")
```

Comment: Can you show us what you're trying to do and the error it returns?

Comment: The `print()` does not use your `Bale()` class at all. I'd add a description of what you are trying to do. From your current wording / code it is hard to tell. Also, when writing a [minimal working example](/help/mcve), it is a good idea to either avoid `input()` or specify what did you typed. Content-wise, It feels like what you want to do could be done using a `dict()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really to do with memory locations. It's just that the variable `bale1`, even if it contains the string `"sewer1"`, has nothing to do with the actual variable named `sewer1`.

To do this you probably want a dictionary instead of all those separate variables.

```
bales = {
    "sewer1": Bale(240, 18, 24),
    "c9001": Bale(480, 8, 32),
    "ips1": Bale(120, 30, 30),
    "sewer2": Bale(240, 20, 28),
    "c9002": Bale(480, 10, 30),
    "ips2": Bale (120, 12, 60),
    "sewer3": Bale(240, 32, 40),
    "c9003": Bale(480, 10, 40),
    "ips2": Bale(120, 32, 48)
}
```

Now you can do:

```
bale_requested = input("What bale do you want?")
bale1 = bales[bale_requested]
```

which looks up the given name in the dictionary, to find the corresponding Bale object.